# Select statement returning the IDs backwards

Tags: mysql, select, geometry, sql-order-by

I have a table with some primary IDs inserted.

In anoter post i have already done i was provided half of the answer i requested and i am thankful for this. ([MySQL select statement returning results in circle mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60040212/mysql-select-statement-returning-results-in-circle-mode))

I tried to accomplish the other half with no luck. What i want to achieve is a select statement that will get me the opposite of the below example.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

---

The select statement i was provided with:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id > 5 DESC, id;
```

Returns 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5

---

I also need a select statement to return:

5 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 9 - 8 - 7 - 6

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there any logic in the order you want the results returned?

Comment: Salmon thank you for your interest. I have some scrolling cards. I want when the user is swipping left and reaches the start to retrieve the last 10 rows also in the same query. The answer below suits my needs! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
ORDER BY id < 6 DESC, id DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/drsVfEJGcyqL3Loe5QW9p7/2).
Results:

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 5   |
| 4   |
| 3   |
| 2   |
| 1   |
| 9   |
| 8   |
| 7   |
| 6   |
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am an sql starter, i tried but could not understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From your earlier question, it seems you need ways to find the **next** and **previous** item in a database.  This assumes

- you know the `id` of the current item
- the `id` is a primary key or other unique value
- **next** gets the next higher `id` value
- **previous** gets the next lower `id` value
- when you get to either end of the range of id values, you get nothing back... there isn't any **next** or **previous**.

Here's how to get the **next** id.

```
 SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id > [[[current_id]]] ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

And, similarly, here's how to get the **previous** value.

```
 SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id < [[[current_id]]] ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 1
```

These queries return just one row, or no rows if there's no **next** or **previous**

There's not much to be gained from a conditional ordering scheme when you only need a single value

Comment: No, i need a circle select. i SWIPE SOME CARDS SO, When i tend to reach to the end i need it to return some of the first records also and the reverse. When i tend to reach to the start to retrun some of the last rows also. Forpas answer above is good for me. Thank you for your time!